# How to create a compeletely transparent window with MFC?

Tags: mfc, window, transparent

I want to create a completely transparent window with MFC, but I don't know how to do this. Can you tell me the way?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use layered windows for transparency effects.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx.  Be sure to set the WS_EX_LAYERED bit and to use UpdateLayeredWindow.  This allows you to trap messages even though the window isn't visible to the user.

Answer (score 0):

By transparent I assume you mean invisible, not translucent. You can set the window's region to an empty region. Take a look at [SetWindowRgn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534845.aspx) and the [Region Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536680(VS.85).aspx) in the Win32 API. There may be some equivalent MFC classes and methods (e.g. [CRgn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa312990(VS.60).aspx)) if you want to avoid pure Win32 calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want invisible, then you can simply clear the WS_VISIBLE bit in the windowstyle. Override PreCreateWindow and ensure this flag is cleared.

Alternatively, you can create a window that only processes messages by specifying HWND_MESSAGE as the parent hwnd in the CreateWindow calls.