# MFC How to draw over all windows

Tags: windows, graphics, mfc, gdi

I'm familiar with MFC and GDI, but I've stumbled upon something I can't really put into perspective. Can I draw something (actually, all I need is a few dots) on top of all windows, and keep 'em there, as if thay are "always on top"? It's an addon to an application, so MFC is mandatory.

Tnx in advance.

Comment: Where do you want the dots to show up? The titlebar? On top of other controls? If so, do they span controls?

Comment: The most correct answer would be anywhere, actually. I'm not talking only about the applications window, I mean anywhere on the screen, even if the application is minimized, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to draw anywhere on the screen and have it stick. Your best option is to create a transparent top-level window with the graphics you need. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438270/how-to-create-a-compeletely-transparent-window-with-mfc), but I'm sure you can find others.